# Laravel - Middleware for route always 403

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

`App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ExampleController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    dd('index');
}
```

`app\Policies\ExamplePolicy.php`

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

`app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Models\Example' => 'App\Policies\ExamplePolicy',
];
```

`routes/admin.php`

```
Route::get('example', [ExampleController::class, 'index'])->middleware('can:viewAny,App\Models\Example')
```

But the `->middleware('can:viewAny,App\Models\Example')` always returns 403, and when I remove it, the `dd('index')` will run.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean this happens when you're signed in

Comment: I didn't know I should sign in first. Anyways I logged in but same result. 403

Comment: what is the output of `php artisan route:list --path example`  keep ur middleware

Answer (score 1):

Although I have logged in, the `auth()->user()` has been null due to the separation of the `admin` and others. So just by adding `web` to the middleware, it worked.

```
Route::get('example', [ExampleController::class, 'index'])->middleware(['web', 'can:viewAny,App\Models\Example'])
```